# WordPress update all posts(TinyMCE Advanced)

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-rest-api

I had a problem that all the text was messy... no `<br>` no `<p>`...
So I did download plugin TinyMCE Advanced...
And it did fix the problem...
BUT...
It only works on the new posts... the posts that were created after the plugin installation... all posts that were created before, are messy....
So i found out that to fix it i need to enter every single post and click on update post...
the problem is, i have over 2000 posts... i can't update them one by one....it's will take a lot of time...
There is a way to update all posts in wordpress?(wp_update_post did not worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to do a console script and loop all posts. Then apply the filter the_editor_content on the content. Make sure you also set post_modified again or you will get new time on all posts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to write your own loop that iterates the update over all your old posts.